# How to disable ability for Windows user to manually change system time via AdjustTokenPrivileges?

Tags: c++, windows, security

I'm using the function below to disable SeSystemtimePrivilege on a token obtained from:

```
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
```

The function runs with no errors, but the ability to change the time manually in Windows 7 is still enabled. I think this is because I'm setting privileges for the current process (my program) and not the current user. Is there a way to get an access token for the currently logged in user, or should I be getting the token for the date/time control panel, or is there another way entirely I should be approaching this?

Again, the goal is for the Win7 logged-in user to not be able to change the system time. I don't have access to group policy on the target machines, so I have to disable this function programmatically. The program is ATL/MFC, so I have access to the CAccessToken class if that would be helpful.

```
BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
    ) 
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
            NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
            lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
            &luid ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges(
           hToken, 
           FALSE, 
           &tp, 
           sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 
           (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 
           (PDWORD) NULL) )
    { 
          printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
          return FALSE; 
    } 

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
          printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
          return FALSE;
    } 

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Non-administrators can't change the system date/time since Vista (XP if not running as an admin or power user), so this shouldn't be necessary. If they're administrators already (which they would have to be unless your app is requesting elevation), I'm not sure you can disable the privilege. (Note I said "not sure", not "you can't".)

Comment: The user who installs and runs the program could be an Administrator. I don't have any control over that, unfortunately.

Comment: Your process is running under the same access as the user who started it, unless you specifically asked for elevation to Administrator. If your app isn't running under Admin access, it can't change the privilege. If it is, it's getting the token for Admin, and I'm not sure you can disable the Admin from changing the system time. I'm pretty sure the only way to do it for all non-Admins globally is to use group policy; to do it for individual users you'd have to get their individual access token and set/remove the privilege for that particular token. Again, not sure of this though. :)

Comment: I'm willing to get users' individual access tokens and try removing the privilege that way, but I don't know how to get a user's token as opposed to a process or thread.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I mean I can see some specific cases where this is desirable, e.g. a point-of-sale system. But if it's a POS, you'd typically have control of the whole system and the users are not running as admin so this would be a non-issue. OTOH if it's for a general computer this is a very bad idea. If a user is running as admin they should be allowed to do anything, including changing the system time.

Comment: The user's home internet usage is being monitored, and changing the system time would allow them to bypass certain restrictions.

Comment: This just can't go anywhere.  If you can't enforce user privileges then you also can't stop them from stopping *you* to mess with their processes.  Which they'll surely will if you try to take key system management tasks away from them.  Security is enforced by the system admin, not a program.

Comment: Why not just have a timer that executes once a minute (or so) and decreases the quota? Then they can happily change the time all they want and you still can limit their access to the Internet.

Comment: I can't really go into a lot of detail about how the monitoring works in public. Let's just say that there are legal ramifications if they tamper with our processes. The user's internet access needs to be shut down during certain hours of the day, and some information that's sent up to our server is tagged with the local time. So, changing that time arbitrarily is a problem. If what I'm trying to do can't be done that's fine, but the decision to not even attempt it would have to be made above my pay grade.

Comment: Ok, take it easy. We're not here to shoot you down, just trying to help you find a better solution. Why not ask your server what time it is? If there's a difference in timezone between the users computer and the server, just record the timezone at install time (so you'll have it even if the user should change it).

Comment: I'm not upset; I get why what I'm trying to do is a bad idea in most circumstances. I just can't discuss details in public freely enough to defend attempting it in this case. If it can't be done, certainly checking against server time is an option, as is processing the WM_TIMECHANGE message. But I was assigned to try the lockdown idea, and I think the only way it could possibly work is with a user access token and I don't know how to get that. It might not work anyway, and at that point I'm happy to go back to my boss and say the best I can do is notify of a time change not prevent one.

Comment: Or maybe I could go the opposite way and let them change the time however they want, but have my program sync the local system time to some known source (our server, time.nist.gov, etc.) at regular intervals. That's probably a better way to go, but I'm still curious to try the privilege thing to see if it would work.

Comment: Ok, unless you're willing to write a kernel-mode driver to patch the kernel (which won't even work in Vista and later), I think you've stumbled upon a dead-end here. The original user access token is created and owned by winlogon and there's no way to get a hold of it from user space. A kernel driver could patch the kernel function implementing LogonUser() altering the token before returning it to winlogon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AdjustTokenPrivileges()` would only have any effect on the current process.  You could use `LsaRemoveAccountRights()`, but that is extreme for what you are trying to achieve.  Also, if the user is an administrator they could just re-grant their account that right (and it won't have any effect until they logout and login again).

Whatever you're trying to do, being dependent on the client machine for your business logic looks to be the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments and previous answer have already pointed out, you'll need an awfully big hammer. There's one such hammer: `GINA.DLL`. The logon processing performed by `WinLogon` can be [tailored](http://www.codealias.info/technotes/custom_pre-logon_processing_in_ms_windows_using_gina_hooks) by providing a custom GINA.DLL.